# Laravel/Vue-router not rendering pages properly

Tags: laravel, vue.js, render, vue-router

## Scenario

I'm developing a web application using

- Laravel 5.6.3
- Vue 2.5.7
- VueRouter 3.0.1

## Setup

I'm using `VueRouter`like

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import fooPage from './components/pages/fooPage.vue';
import barPage from './components/pages/barPage.vue';
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/foo',
        component: fooPage
    },
    {
        path: '/bar',
        component: barPage,
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});
```

With

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
})
```

And a:

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

In my markup.

## Issue

When I perform a hard refresh on root `(/)`, I can navigate between pages and the content loads fine. However, when I refresh on, say `/foo` - I can no longer navigate between the different pages properly.

Comment: You need some kind of URL rewriting. See https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue SPA url not working with history mode enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940951/vue-spa-url-not-working-with-history-mode-enabled)

Comment: Also see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/vue-router-in-laravel-cant-go-directly-to-a-url?page=1

Comment: Putting the laravel slug in there used to work for me. It's not in this instance. Interestingly enough, putting the script tag which pulls in my main compiled js file before jQuery on my index page is kinda working...

Comment: @Phil defaulting routes and defining slugs are my usual go-tos, but i noticed something was different in this project

Comment: So if you refresh on `/foo` you still see the content, just can't interact with it (or at least go to other routes)?

Comment: @devk that's the correct.. if I refresh on /foo the behaviour is strange, ill whip up a quick jsfid

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking towards this https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html.

Depending on your server's configuration, you should follow the steps in that web page.

I will copy `apache` and `nginx` ones since they are widely used.

---

Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

Nginx

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```